# Checking diagram of implications between modes of convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence

[image]

I learned about the definitions of these convergences. Is my diagram correct?

Comment: Sure convergence (rather called pointwise convergence) does not imply mean square convergence.

Comment: @Did You mean that Mean square convergence is different kind of others, right? So, sure convergence is not in convergence. Thank you, I am going to think more about this.

Comment: "Mean square convergence is different kind of others" No idea what you mean by that.